# Spring integration and batch job is running in every poll

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-integration

I don't understand spring integration with `JobLaunchingGateway` behavior. I have example config:

```java
    public SftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec sftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec() {
        return Sftp.inboundAdapter(ftpFileSessionFactory())
                .preserveTimestamp(true)
                .deleteRemoteFiles(false)
                .remoteDirectory(integrationProperties.getRemoteDirectory())
                .filter(sftpFileListFilter())
                .localDirectory(new File(integrationProperties.getLocalDirectory()));
    }

    public PollerSpec pollerSpec() {
        PollerSpec cron = Pollers.cron(integrationProperties.getPollerCron());
        cron.maxMessagesPerPoll(integrationProperties.getMessagePerPoll());

        return cron;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sftpInboundFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(sftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec(), pc -> pc.poller(pollerSpec()))
                .transform(fileMessageToJobRequest())
                .handle(jobLaunchingGateway())
                .handle(message -> {
                    logger.info("Handle message: {}", message.getPayload());
                })
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway() {
        SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        simpleJobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SyncTaskExecutor());

        JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway = new JobLaunchingGateway(simpleJobLauncher);
        return jobLaunchingGateway;
    }

    private ChainFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpFileListFilter() {
        ChainFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> chainFileListFilter = new ChainFileListFilter<>();
        chainFileListFilter.addFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xlsx"));
        chainFileListFilter.addFilter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(), "INT"));
        return chainFileListFilter;
    }
```

If I set polling every 1 minute, the job will be created every minute. I don't see any new record in `MetaDataStore`.

When I comment line with `.handle(jobLaunchingGateway())`

```java
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sftpInboundFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(sftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec(), pc -> pc.poller(pollerSpec()))
                .transform(fileMessageToJobRequest())
//                .handle(jobLaunchingGateway())
                .handle(message -> {
                    logger.info("Handle message: {}", message.getPayload());
                })
                .get();
    }
```

Everything works as expected.

I expected that SFTP fetch new file(s) and then create new job for each file.

I don't understand why I don't see records in `MetaDataStore` when I `JobLaunchingGateway` is enabled.

Can you help me and explain this?

I am new in spring integration and batch?

Comment: How does it work if you comment out the last `handle()` instead of this gateway?

Comment: If I comment last `handle()` then I get exception: `Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available`.
I added nullChannel and exception disappeared, but behavior is the same :(

Comment: Ok. That means `JobLaunchingGateway` is not blocking. Good. Do you mean with a `JobLaunchingGateway` you see entries in the metadata store, but with it do not? Although the SFTP channel adapter is producing messages every minute and probably for the same local file? No new file on SFTP side. Right?

Comment: I mean with `JobLaunchinGateway` I don't see entries in the metadata store, but without I see. The rest is right. I made another simple Job and it works well. I think it is something wrong with Job.

Comment: Any chances to see a simple Spring Boot project to play with? I really want to understand the problem and how to reproduce it.

Comment: I will prepare a sample project over the weekend.

Comment: I think that is something wrong with my reader. I will try to solve this problem myself first.

Comment: Hmmm... I have it, but I don't understand this. In my reader I use Apache POI. When I call `workbook.close();` then job is repeated and without this line everything works well. Do you have any idea why this is happening? What is the reason? Can you explain this?